# MultipleChoiceField: как указать выбранные значения в запросе

Tags: python, django

Есть объект MultipleChoiceField:

```
# forms.py

options = []
for t in DocumentType.objects.all().values():
    options.append((t['globalid'], t['type']))
doc_types = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=options, required=False,initial=True,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Мне нужен запрос, который из таблицы Document выберет только документы отмеченных типов (поле doc_type в коде views.py - внешний ключ с данными из таблицы DocumentType). По  логике что-то типа такого запроса, но этот код не работает:

```
# views.py
doc_list = Document.objects
doc_list = doc_list.filter(Q(doc_type__icontains=doc_types.value))
```

Подскажите, как обратиться в запросе к  выбранным элементам CheckboxSelectMultiple, а то я не нахожу внятного описания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, обратиться к этому объекту можно так:

```
  if doc_types: 
        doc_list = doc_list.filter(doc_type__in = doc_types)
```